# How to change value in multiple CSV cells?

Tags: python, loops, csv, automation

I have 118 CSVs, I need to go into each CSV and change F1, F2, F3 and so on to 0.

For example, in csv1, F1 = 0, in csv2, F2 = 0, in csv3, F3 = 0 and so on.

The CSV has headers:
[image: as shown in the example]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: So you wish to make all of the `F` column `0` (apart from the header) ?

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer below. Do not edit the question

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming all of your CSV files have the same format, and that you are trying to set column `F` to be 0 for all of them.

You can use Python CSV library to help you as follows:

```
import csv
import glob

for filename in glob.glob('*.csv'):
    print(f'Processing: {filename}')
    
    with open(filename) as f_input:
        csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
        header = next(csv_input)
        rows = [[*row[:5], '0'] for row in csv_input]

    with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as f_output:
        csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
        csv_output.writerow(header)
        csv_output.writerows(rows)
```

This reads all `.csv` files from a given folder and changes the `Multi Col 2` values to `0`. It does this for all rows but leaves the header the same.

Comment: Hello All, Thank you for response, I have solved the problem. I had 118 csv, If my Csv was saved as 1 i need to changed F1 to 0, if the filename was 2, i needed to change f2 to 0 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

[**Mr. Evans**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4985733/martin-evans) has [pretty neat code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69606867) using Python CSV library, so I will expand on it a bit to answer y
our specific question.

```
import csv
import glob

file_count = 0

for filename in glob.glob('*.csv'):
    file_count += 1
    print(f'Processing: {filename}')

    with open(filename) as f_input:
        csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
        header = next(csv_input)
        line_count = 0
        rows = []
        for row in csv_input:
            line_count += 1
            if line_count == file_count:
                rows.append([*row[:5], '0'])
            else:
                rows.append([*row[:6]])        
        
    with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as f_output:
        csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
        csv_output.writerow(header)
        csv_output.writerows(rows)
```

Note: the code will run for all the `.csv` files in the working directory and will run through the files in an alphabetic order.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I made my own solution, it is a lot less classy than the ones posted here. But I automated it from the point of needing x number of files to amending the col/row.

```py
#==============================================================================

# Import the necessary packages
import os
#import glob
import shutil
import pathlib
import pandas as pd
#import numpy as np

#==============================================================================

InputPath = 'F:\\cells\\bc_dbase\\bc_dbase1.csv'

OutputPath = 'F:\\cells\\bc_dbase'

str1 = 'Name '
str2 = 'Mult Col 2'

NoStart = 1
NoEnd = 119

#==============================================================================

# Create complete path of folders
def CreatePath(FullPath,File=False):
    Parts = pathlib.Path(FullPath).parts
    for [n1,Folder] in enumerate(Parts):
        if File==True and n1==len(Parts)-1 and "." in Parts[n1]:
            continue
        elif n1==0:
            FolderPath = Parts[n1]
        else:
            FolderPath = os.path.join(FolderPath,Folder)
        if os.path.exists(FolderPath)==False:
            os.mkdir(FolderPath)

#==============================================================================

# Delete folder
def DeleteFolder(FullPath):
    FullPath = pathlib.Path(FullPath)
    try:
        shutil.rmtree(FullPath)
    except:
        pass

#==============================================================================

CreatePath(OutputPath,File=False)

[FolderPath,File] = os.path.split(InputPath)
[FileName,FileExt] = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(InputPath))


ReversedFileName = FileName[::-1]
AdjFileName = FileName


for n1 in reversed(range(len(AdjFileName))):
    char = FileName[n1]
    if char.isdigit():
        AdjFileName = AdjFileName[:n1] + AdjFileName[(n1+1):]
    else: break;


Data1 = pd.read_csv(InputPath)
Data2 = pd.DataFrame.copy(Data1)
NameCols = Data1.columns
if str2 in NameCols:
    Data2.loc[:,str2] = 1

for n1 in range(NoStart,NoEnd+1):
    NewFile = AdjFileName + str(n1) + FileExt
    NewFilePath = os.path.join(OutputPath,NewFile)
    Data3 = pd.DataFrame.copy(Data2)
    index = Data3[Data3[str1]==n1].index[0]
    Data3.loc[index,str2] = 0
    
    Data3.to_csv(NewFilePath, index=False)
    print('[INFO] Storing file:',NewFilePath)



                
                
            
#==============================================================================
```